# dropped repaired collection space not relinquished in mongo

Tags: mongodb

According to df, we have only a few K of space left.

I identified an expendable collection in mongo that was taking up 299 GB. I dropped it, then ran repairDatabase. All the advice I've read says this will relinquish the space I've freed. But according to df, nothing has changed; we still have nearly no space left.

What can I do to get this space freed up?

Comment: Are you sure repair succeeded? Because, repair requires free disk space to work but you are saying your disk was almost full.

Comment: repairDatabase returned {"ok": 1.0}. I believe that means that it worked.